# Getting User Name from Within HttpSessionListener

Tags: java, servlets

I would like to get the username from within `HttpSessionListener.sessionCreated()`.  When I say username, I mean specifically that name that is returned by `HttpServletRequest.getRemoteUser()`.

Obviously, there must have been a `HttpServletRequest` object that caused the session to be created (and hence the `sessionCreated()` call).  But how do I access it from within `sessionCreated()`?  The `HttpSessionEvent` object passed into `sessionCreated()` appears to provide no way to get at the `HttpServletRequest` object that caused the session to be created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The HttpSessionListener does not have access to the HttpServletRequest object because it is invoked when no request has been made—to notify of session destruction or creation.

So, a Filter would be better places where you can add username = request.getRemoteUsr() into session.

Example - Filter Code

```
String username = request.getRemoteUsr() ;
session.setAttribute("username",username);
```

and then retrive this username in sessionCreated method as

```
String username = (String)session.getAttribute("username");
```

i hope you will get the same username of the same request which has created this session in HttpSessionListener sessionCreated() method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I will try what you suggest.  One thing is unclear, you say the HttpSessionListener is invoked when no request has been made, but I thought that there had to be a call to request.getSession() in order for a session to be created, so isn't it true there must be a request object when the session is created?

Comment: I don't think this solution could work, since the `sessionCreated` event is sent when the session is created and at this point, the attribute `username` is not set yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
// set
session.setAttribute("username", request.getRemoteUser();

// get
String un = (String) session.getAttribute("username");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `HttpSessionAttributeListener`:

```
public class UsernameHttpSessionAttributeListener implements HttpSessionAttributeListener {

    @Override
    public void attributeAdded(HttpSessionBindingEvent httpSessionBindingEvent) {
        if (httpSessionBindingEvent.getName().equals("username")) {
            // do something
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Of course, you need to set the attribute `username` in the HTTP session anywhere, for instance in a servlet filter.