# LDAP on Jboss 6.4

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ldap

I'm want to implement a LDAP validation in Jboss 6.4, I'm newbie in this area. I want to explain how I understand the process, and I would like to receive a opinion about if the process if is correct or not, because here there are several ways to do it.

1.- Define a security domain in my Jboss 6.4, here I will put the LDAP Role: **LdapUserMyWeb**, and the password for this Role.

**login-config.xml**

```
<application-policy name="LdapMyApp">
 <authentication>
 <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.LdapExtLoginModule" flag="required" >
 <module-option name="java.naming.factory.initial">com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory</module-option>
 <module-option name="java.naming.provider.url">ldap://localhost:10389</module-option> <!-- LDAP url-->
 <module-option name="java.naming.security.authentication">simple</module-option>

 <module-option name="bindDN">uid=LdapUserMyWeb,ou=system</module-option>
 <module-option name="bindCredential">myPassword</module-option>
 <module-option name="baseCtxDN">ou=people,o=sevenSeas</module-option> 
 <module-option name="rolesCtxDN">ou=groups,o=sevenSeas</module-option>

 </login-module>
 </authentication>
</application-policy>
```

2.- I will define in  **jboss-web.xml** in the WEB-INF

```
<jboss-web>
  <security-domain>java:/jaas/LdapMyApp</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```

3.- Finally I need to restrict the specific urls or servlets to certain roles. In this example, we will only allow access for users in the role **“LdapUserMyWeb”**,

```
<security-constraint>
  <display-name>All resources</display-name>
  <web-resource-collection>
   <web-resource-name>All resources</web-resource-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
   <role-name>LdapUserMyWeb</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
 </security-constraint>
 <login-config>
  <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
 </login-config>
```

3.- In my Web App (jee6) I will define HttpSessionEvent and HttpSessionListener, when the session is created for the Role: **LdapUserMyWeb**.

Here I need to check if the User and Password exist in the LDAP, How I can
 take from the Object Session this info from LDAP??

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration of LDAP looks about right.

It's not possible to retrieve the username from within the HttpSessionListener but you can with a filter. Please look at: [Getting User Name from Within HttpSessionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12833275/getting-user-name-from-within-httpsessionlistener)